# LEFT JOIN con varias tablas y claúsula WHERE

Tags: mysql

Buenas a todos, estoy realizando un control de acceso en mysql y tengo una tabla `acceso` con relación a otras tres:

```
acceso (fecha_hora,usuario,servicio,parada)
usuario (dni,nombre)
servicio (id,nombre)
parada (id,nombre)
```

Necesito mostrar el nombre de las tres en lugar del id y lo he conseguido de esta forma:

```
SELECT acceso.fecha_hora,usuario.nombre as usuarionombre,
       usuario.apellidos as usuarioapellido,
       servicio.nombre as servicio,
       parada.nombre as parada 
       FROM acceso 
       LEFT JOIN usuario ON usuario.dni = acceso.usuario
       LEFT JOIN servicio ON servicio.id = acceso.servicio     
       LEFT JOIN parada ON parada.id = acceso.parada 
       ORDER BY fecha_hora desc LIMIT 0,15
```

Pero a la hora de introducir una clausula WHERE como usuario.dni="123456789X" no consigo que me muestre correctamente los resultados.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de introducir la clausula WHERE aquí? ¿o quizás no debería usar aquí LEFT JOIN?

Muchas gracias de antemano

EDITO:
Simplemente tenía que introducir la clausula where justo delante de ORDER BY.
Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Cual viene siendo tu query donde agregas el WHERE?

Comment: Como bien dice @ Lixus dónde has probado a poner el where? Puedes usarlo en tu query pero debe ir antes del orden by.

Comment: Que significa: "no consigo que me muestre correctamente los resultados"? en lo posible agrega siempre un ejemplo del resultado obtenido y lo que deseas obtener.

Answer (score 4):

Tu consulta con el `WHERE` debería ser así:

```
   SELECT acceso.fecha_hora,usuario.nombre as usuarionombre,
          usuario.apellidos as usuarioapellido,
          servicio.nombre as servicio,
          parada.nombre as parada 
     FROM acceso 
LEFT JOIN usuario ON usuario.dni = acceso.usuario
LEFT JOIN servicio ON servicio.id = acceso.servicio     
LEFT JOIN parada ON parada.id = acceso.parada 
    WHERE usuario.dni="123456789X"
 ORDER BY fecha_hora desc LIMIT 0,15
```

Pero necesitas especificar si la columna `usuario.dni` es de tipo **entero** o **cadena** supongo que por la *x* que tiene *(123456789X)* es de tipo `varchar`.

Si es así solo verifica que los datos en la base estén correctos y existan.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, intentaba incluir el where dentro de los left join y era mucho mas sencillo. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: De nada, saludos!!

Comment: Da por aceptada esta respuesta, para cerrar la pregunta. Saludos