# Traer datos relacionados de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas una `types` y la otra `plates` que son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quiero traer el `type` de ese plato, como lo haría?

ejemplo: Tengo un plato con el id 1 y tiene el `id_type 2`, y quiero traer el nombre de ese `type` o en su defecto la `tupla` completa de ese `type`

Comment: prueba con un `JOIN` de este modo y me dices si te funcionó `SELECT types.name, plates.name
FROM types
JOIN plates ON types.id = plates.id_type;`

Comment: @AlfredoPaz si, es que ese ya lo habia intentado, pero me trae todos y yo solo quiero con el id del plato que yo le de

Comment: entonces agregare un ejemplo con `where`

Comment: si, si gracias. con el where ya me funciona

Comment: te lo anexo como respuesta si te parece bien

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84506/left-join-con-varias-tablas-y-cla%C3%BAsula-where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trabajalo con `JOIN` para unir las 2 tablas ya que tienen en común el `id_type` y para filtrar por un valor específico que tu le des usa  `where` para delimitar a donde quieres que se haga la búsqueda.

Desde la perspectiva de un plano cartesiano, el uso de `JOIN` o también conocido como `INNER JOIN` va a retornar los resultados que estén vinculados en ambas tablas; es decir en un escenario donde una tabla users, esta vinculada con una tabla posts; este mismo `JOIN` va a retornar todos los usuarios que tienen posts registrados, omitiendo tanto los usuarios sin posts o los posts sin usuarios

** EJEMPLO **

```
SELECT types.name, plates.name
FROM types
JOIN plates ON types.id = plates.id_type
WHERE plates.id = 1;
```

> El valor 1 que coloque sustituyelo por la variable o el valor exacto
>   que deseas que ayude a filtrar tu búsqueda; de preferencia por cada campo que consultes precedelo por el nombre de la tabla a la que pertenece para evitar ambiguedades; de este modo: `tablaName.columnaName`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvio mucho